# How can I sort my files in Google Photos by size?

Tags: google-photos

Google is now giving me the message that:

> You’re out of storage space and will soon be unable to send or receive emails until you free up space or purchase additional storage.

I suspect that most of my storage space
is occupied by large videos in Google Photos.
How do I sort my files/videos in Google Photos by size?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/quota

You can convert them to high quality so you can reduce the size.

https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6314648

Comment: If you access https://photos.google.com/settings and click "recover space" it will automatically compress every photo in google photos so  it doesn't take up space

Comment: This does not answer the question:  Google Photos <> Google Drive.

Comment: The requested operation is now possible... see my answer :).

Answer (score 14):

This is now, finally, possible @ https://one.google.com/storage/management!

See the full blog post on it here: https://blog.google/products/google-one/free-features/

And also https://photos.google.com/u/0/quotamanagement/large

Answer (score 2):

You can do it Google One now: You can't download them, but can see the photo's and delete them:

https://one.google.com/storage/management

Answer (score 0):

Nope, the search address (https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/quota) you posted does not work fully... ok, it works yes BUT for some bizarre reason it leaves out many files so you may not get all the video files (or any video files with that search string, that's what happened to me).

First, determine whether your videos have a fixed abbreviation in the file name. For example, my phone camera takes videos and labels them as "VID_xxxxxxxx" where the xxxxxxxx is the date of filming the video. Like for example VID_20171101 is a video file I shot on January eleventh on 2017 (wow, I just used a time machine).

So:

1. Go to Drive
2. Search: VID*

Now your Google Drive shows all the files starting with VID. Of course replace the search string "VID" with whatever your video files are labeled with.

Comment: Simply searching Google Photos for the word `videos` will also return a [listing](https://photos.google.com/search/_tv_videos) of only videos -- but regardless of filename or filetype (and still not necessarily sorted by size)

Answer (score 0):

Seems google photos lacks quite some options here. If you want to manually select which photos to convert, list them by size, or even see whether they are currently stored in raw or high quality form, you are out of luck. You can sometimes sort files by size in google drive/storage, but not google photos:
https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/search?q=type:image

You can download all of them via takeout and do it offline or in some other platform.

However, probably it's not a problem to convert everything to high quality. And if you do care, perhaps you should consider a different platform.

Also see this link for when it matters:

https://www.phonearena.com/news/Google-Photos-High-quality-vs-Original-Whats-the-difference-and-should-you-care_id93938